# vba finding weekend and choosing array response

Tags: vba, date, select, weekday

How do I get column b to display "none" on a weekend? The code runs, but I don't see anything different than what would be without the select case.

```
Sub fixandresponse()
Dim count As Integer
Dim thedate As Date
Dim typesofproblems() As Variant
thedate = DateSerial(2014, 9, 1)

typesofproblems = Array("bought new hardware", "Phone Support", "New User Request", "Rent Hardware")


Select Case WeekdayName(thedate)

Case 1, 7: Instr(typesofproblems) = "none"
For count = 2 To 366

Range("B" & count) = typesofproblems(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 3))
Range("A" & count) = thedate

thedate = thedate + 1
Next

End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: it doesnt work if I remove the select case thing it runs. but I want it to say none during the weekends, and Im not sure how.

Comment: Also it now says invalid procedure call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

(1) weekdayname() does not return a number, it requires an integer indicating the day in the week you want, and it returns a string with the actual name eg "Monday".  The function you want is WeekDay().

(2) To iterate through theDate, The loop was in the wrong place.

(3) The instr() function does not place a value into an array, it will search a string and return the starting position of the search string as an integer.

Try this:

```
Sub fixandresponse()

Dim count As Integer

Dim thedate As Date

Dim typesofproblems() As Variant

thedate = DateSerial(2014, 9, 1)

typesofproblems = Array("bought new hardware", "Phone Support", "New User Request", "Rent Hardware")
For count = 2 To 366
    Select Case Weekday(thedate)
            Case 1, 7
                Range("B" & count) = "none"
                Range("A" & count) = thedate
        Case Else
                Range("B" & count) = typesofproblems(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 3))
                Range("A" & count) = thedate
    End Select
    thedate = thedate + 1
Next



End Sub
```